# Lidskii's theorem for non trace-class operators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Lidskii's theorem states that for a trace-class operators, the trace is actually equal to the sum of eigenvalues.

Now, there are operators with finite trace that are not trace-class. Of course, in such a case, talking about a trace is a bit dangerous, as it might depend on both, the ordering of the basis elements and the choice of basis.

However, let's say our operator $T$ acts on a Hilbert space and is a Hilbert-Schmidt operator. In addition, we assume that there exist a choice of orthonormal basis such that $\operatorname{tr}(T)$ exists.

I ask: Does this imply that the eigenvalues of $T$ can be ordered in such a way that

$$\operatorname{tr}(T)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \lambda_i?$$

Or put differently, is there any connection between the trace and the sum of eigenvalues for non-trace class operators?

Comment: It does work if $T$ is also self-adjoint, but in a rather trivial way: either $\sum |\lambda_n|<\infty$, so $T$ is trace class, or $\sum |\lambda_n|=\infty$, and then the series can be made to converge to anything by rearranging suitably.